# In any 3d object, how do you calculate the rotation of that object so the visible part with most surface area is pointing to the camera/eye?

Tags: 3d, angle, spheres

Example:
Take a sphere and cut it in  half.
If you point the curved part of the half sphere to the camera its the visible part with most surface area

Comment: Compute the center-of-gravity and then the principal axes. Take the shortest axis as the direction to the camera. This is of course only an approximation or a general best guess, as the actual configuration could actually counter-act this logic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As there is no way to actually store an arbitrary 3d shape on a computer, there's also no way to do computations on it.  You might want to narrow down your question to something like "convex 3d polyhedrons" or something.